# What's a good regular expression for real numbers in Java?

Tags: java, regex

What's a good regular expression for real numbers in Java?

I created the regex `([-]?[\\d]*\\.[\\d]*)` and tested it against the following expected outputs:

```
in                  out        works?
--------------------------------------
qwerty34.34abcd     34.34       yes
qwe-34.34.34abcd    -34.34      no
+17.-9abc           17.0        yes
-.abc0              0.0         no
```

I have to get out exactly what the column(out).
Please provide a regex that passes all of these tests.

Comment: Why isn't second line considered working?

Comment: But -34.34.34 is an invalid real number , perhaps!

Comment: -34.34 is the correct output for a regex looking for a real number in -34.34.34. Because -34.34.34 is not a real number. The same applies to your last example.

Comment: But in second test NumberFormatException: multiple points! I'm not convert to -34.34 .

Comment: Right, so they are your EXPECTED results, not your actual ones. You didn't explain that. See my answer.

Comment: @Anirudh Presumably because 0 = 0.0 when represented as a float?

Comment: What about `1e+100`?

Answer (score 7):

Try the following:

```
((\+|-)?([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?)|((\+|-)?\.?[0-9]+)
```

This will match real numbers, including integers, with or without a sign (and with or without a number before the decimal point).

Comment: `it's not clear whether it should be "34" or ".34" that is matched` The problem is with your regex. Your regex does not match the latter, so it will skip ahead and match `34`.

Comment: You should also mention why this works better: The `+`-opertator matches 1-n repetitions, while the `*`-operator matches 0-n, so it also matches no numbers at all.

Comment: @AntP: Your regex accepts `+.55.55`, which is likely to be rejected by the OP.

Comment: Modified once again. Probably unnecessarily convoluted now, mind.

Comment: Your RE doesn't match `1e9`…

Comment: @DonalFellows It matches the "1" - there was no implication of a requirement to match that kind of exponential notation.

Comment: (note that he asks for "real numbers" not "valid floating point values")

Comment: Expression `((\+|-)?([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?)|((\+|-)?\.?[0-9]+)` does not work for 'qwe-34.34.34abcd'.

Comment: @Vanya - It matches -34.34, which is the first valid real number in the string...

Answer (score 4):

The regular expression must satisfy these requirements:

1. There may be an optional sign.  Try `[+-]?`.
2. There may be 0 or more optional digits. Try `[0-9]*`.
3. There may be a decimal point. Try `[.]` to avoid backslashitis.
4. There may be 0 or more digits after the decimal point. Try `[0-9]*`.
5. At least one of #2 and #4 has a digit.  This would use `[0-9]+`, and it can use alternation.

Does this pattern work: `[+-]?([0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+|[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*)`?  I'm worried about catastrophic backtracking, however.

Answer (score 2):

```
^[+-]?(?:\d+\.?\d*|\d*\.\d+)$
```

- `?`  is for making `+` or `-` optionals
- `?:`  is for non capturing group
- `\`  is an escape char

Answer (score 2):

How about the next one:

```
^-?(([1-9][0-9]*)|(0))(?:\.[0-9]+)?$
```

or the next one if you want to allow the "+" sign:

```
^(-|\+)?(([1-9][0-9]*)|(0))(?:\.[0-9]+)?$
```

BTW, [here's](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) a nice website for testing and sharing regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Or this one: `[0-9]+\.[0-9]*([eE][\+\-]?[0-9]+)?`