# Regular expression for the set of all C real numbers

Tags: qregularexpression, real-number

all the following patterns need to be accepted: 0, +0,-0, any integer, any integer preceded by + or - sign.

.3, 3.14, +3.14159, -3.14159, 0.123, -0.123, .123, +.123

12e+2, 7e-4, 6.3e2, 6.3e+2, 6.3e-2, -6.3e+2

I am a little bit confused about how to make the equation.

Comment: `[+-]?(?:\d*[.]?\d+|\d+[.]?\d*)(?:e[-+]?\d+)?` I couldn't figure it out without alternation because it must have numbers before the decimal or numbers after but not necessarily both.  https://regex101.com/r/ShAWRU/1

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119154/whats-a-good-regular-expression-for-real-numbers-in-java

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.